# Maintain equal width on flexbox columns when adding a margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following two-column layout using flexbox:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  /* Equal width columns */
  flex: 1;
  /* Center content */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  /* Site wide to make images responsive */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Cover column */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: right center;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:focus {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/1*mONNI1lG9VuiqovpnYqicA.jpeg" alt="Bad Ass Cat">
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <h2>Here's a Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam ut ex at fermentum. Proin nec eros at elit mollis porttitor. Vivamus vestibulum luctus metus, ac gravida felis varius nec. Praesent non mauris et tortor lacinia cursus quis at turpis. Nullam scelerisque vitae leo nec convallis. Proin volutpat, est non iaculis facilisis, tellus tortor pulvinar lectus, eu porttitor diam dui eget enim. Praesent non ipsum dui.</p>
    <a href="#">Click Me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the columns are equal in width and height at any viewport width.

I'd like to add a margin to the last column which contains text. Here's what I've tried:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  /* Equal width columns */
  flex: 1;
  /* Center content */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  margin: 96px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  /* Site wide to make images responsive */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Cover column */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: right center;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:focus {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/1*mONNI1lG9VuiqovpnYqicA.jpeg" alt="Bad Ass Cat">
  </div>
    <div class="column content">
      <h2>Here's a Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam ut ex at fermentum. Proin nec eros at elit mollis porttitor. Vivamus vestibulum luctus metus, ac gravida felis varius nec. Praesent non mauris et tortor lacinia cursus quis at turpis. Nullam scelerisque vitae leo nec convallis. Proin volutpat, est non iaculis facilisis, tellus tortor pulvinar lectus, eu porttitor diam dui eget enim. Praesent non ipsum dui.</p>
      <a href="#">Click Me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I've added a margin to the `.content` column to give the text some breathing room. I assumed flexbox would account for the margin, but it doesn't.

Next, I tried the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  /* Equal width columns */
  flex: 1;
  /* Center content */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  margin: 96px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  /* Site wide to make images responsive */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Cover column */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: right center;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:focus {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/1*mONNI1lG9VuiqovpnYqicA.jpeg" alt="Bad Ass Cat">
  </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Here's a Heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam ut ex at fermentum. Proin nec eros at elit mollis porttitor. Vivamus vestibulum luctus metus, ac gravida felis varius nec. Praesent non mauris et tortor lacinia cursus quis at turpis. Nullam scelerisque vitae leo nec convallis. Proin volutpat, est non iaculis facilisis, tellus tortor pulvinar lectus, eu porttitor diam dui eget enim. Praesent non ipsum dui.</p>
        <a href="#">Click Me</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I've added a `<div class="content">` tag with a margin within the text column. The columns are now equal in width at any viewport and there's breathing room for the text. **This is what I am trying to achieve**.

My question: Unfortunately, I'm not able to access the backend for this project, so I'm not able to add a `<div class="content">` tag to the text column. Is there a way to add a margin to the text column without adding a `<div class="content">` tag? I guess I can add a margin to my `<h2>`, `<p>` and `<a>` elements, but I'm hoping there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Use padding instead of margin

Comment: I've tried both margin and padding, both with the same effect.

Comment: Note that `flex: 1;` doesn't make the columns equal width by itself despite what is commented in your code. Flexbox isn't really for that. Why not use grid?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: It's working if you make the code example full screen. Maybe you have a solution?

Comment: @Sam Would you accept just changing your code to CSS grid as a solution? doesn't really answer the problem that was asked.

Comment: @MarcHjorth I'm trying to add a margin to the second column to give the text some breathing room. This can be achieved by adding a `<div class="content">` container within the second column as demonstrated in my question. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: @Laif I'd love to use CSS grid, but it needs to work in older browsers.

Comment: I don't understand why you feel that way, but you can always target the "text-column" with `CSS`, using `nth-child` or `last-of-type`, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @MarcHjorth I'm not able to access the back-end on this project, so adding `<div class="content">` isn't an option. Targeting with `nth-child` doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I've updated my question, so hopefully, it's a little clearer.

Comment: I think I get your issue now. You could target everything inside the "text-column" using `*` - like this `.column:last-of-type > *`. I made an example here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdsfn457/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe flex-basis can help:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.column {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  flex-basis: 50%
}

.two {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 10vw;
}

img {
  display: block;
  /* Site wide to make images responsive */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Cover column */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: right center;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:focus {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column one">
    <img src="https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/1*mONNI1lG9VuiqovpnYqicA.jpeg" alt="Bad Ass Cat">
  </div>
    <div class="column two">

        <h2>Here's a Heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam ut ex at fermentum. Proin nec eros at elit mollis porttitor. Vivamus vestibulum luctus metus, ac gravida felis varius nec. Praesent non mauris et tortor lacinia cursus quis at turpis. Nullam scelerisque vitae leo nec convallis. Proin volutpat, est non iaculis facilisis, tellus tortor pulvinar lectus, eu porttitor diam dui eget enim. Praesent non ipsum dui.</p>
        <a href="#">Click Me</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is, that he can't add additional classes to the DOM, since it comes from a backend, that he can't access. (Otherwise I would've done the same as you. ;))

Comment: It says it is just a two-column layout though, so why not `.grid .column:first-of-type { flex-basis: 50% }` and `.grid .column:last-of-type {   flex: 1; margin: 0 10vw; }`?

Comment: This is great solution, thank you. Thanks to everyone that contributed and your patience.